# How to use $config['base_url'] pagination not based on controller/function (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

How to use `$config['base_url']` pagination not based on `controller/function` but on my route?

For example I have the following route:

```
route['blog/category'] = bloger/category_blog
```

and my `$config['base_url']` for pagination

```
$config['base_url']= base_url().'blog/category
```

while I have a controller with name: `bloger` and method name is `category_blog`.

But when I use this route in `base_url` for pagination the result is page not found because `$config['base_url']` pagination just read directly your name_controller and your function in the controller.

Anybody knows how to fix my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `base_url` on your `controller/function`

```
$config['base_url']= base_url(). 'bloger/category_blog';
```

and add your routes like

```
$route['blog/category/(:any)']  = "bloger/category_blog/$1";
```